# allauth with more then one apps in the django project

Tags: python, django, django-allauth

I'm using django-allauth on my website. Now I am adding one more application to my project for mobile site. Is it possible to use same authentication method (allauth) from my mobile site as well. Is there any help available for the same.

Comment: The question is not clear to me - you mean you have a shared database of the two? if so, then yes, you can just use it with your new project. if you mean you are just adding an app to the project then, no problem, allauth is already there...

Comment: Yes, I am adding new app to the same project. It is using same database.

Comment: In that case, there shouldn't be any problem to use the allauth capabilities. Is something not working? because it is supposed to..

Comment: Thanks reply. I was not able to access authentication data in my template of the new app. I mean in my template {% if user.is_authenticated %} was returning false. I got the mistake I was making. I was returning just "return render_to_response("mobile/index.html")" which as not having context. Changing it to "return render_to_response("mobile/index.html",context_instance=RequestContext(request))" worked. - Thanks